# Why is 438579088 a perfect digit-to-digit invariant?

Tags: number-theory, recreational-mathematics

A PDDI (perfect digit-to-digit invariant) is a number which is also the sum of each of it's digits raised to them self.

My main problem with the number **438579088** being a PDDI is the 7th number - 0. Breaking 438579088 down to check if it's a PDDI or not:

- 4^4 = 256
- 3^3 = 27
- 8^8 = 16777216
- 5^5 = 3125
- 7^7 = 823543
- 9^9 = 387420489
- 0^0 = 1
- 8^8 = 16777216
- 8^8 = 16777216

I had a program to find the sum of these numbers and I've checked it numerous times with different approaches, and each time I receive the number **438579089**, 1 number off 438579088. My hypothesis is that the 0 is being miscalculated - I do seem to remember any number to the power of 0 is 1, however.

In my code, (where num is 438579088) *total* would indeed be 438579088:

```
 for i in str(num):
     if int(i) != 0:
         total += pow(int(i), int(i))
```

but, when I stopped checking if i was 0,

```
for i in str(num):
     total += pow(int(i), int(i))
```

I received 438579089. Why does this happen? This isn't so much a code problem but a mathematical problem. I can't understand why many sources say this number is a PDDI where also saying that 0^0 = 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never come across this before. But one can define concepts however one likes, and a quick check around indicates that a PDDI comes with the convention that $0^0 = 0$. See for instance [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_digit-to-digit_invariant) or [magic-squares.net](http://www.magic-squares.net/narciss.htm).

You might find it interesting to study [Meunchhausen Numbers](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MuenchhausenNumber.html). It is not all obvious to me that there are exactly four Meunchhausen numbers. This gives a base-level interest to using the convention that $0^0 = 0$, since

You might be interested in studiying PDDI numbers using the more standard convention that $0^0 = 1$. I encourage you - go for it! This is part of the attraction of recreational mathematics.